# How to add string.Join separator before each element

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a list of object with a property called `Id`, I'm trying to join of this values to create a piece for a query such as:

```
UNION ALL SELECT 30 UNION ALL SELECT 31 UNION ALL SELECT ...
```

The problem is that I get: `30 UNION ALL SELECT 31 UNION ALL SELECT`

Honestly I can't find a way to get it directly from `string.JOIN`, this is my implementation:

```
string.Join("UNION ALL SELECT ", teams.Skip(1).Select(c => c.Id).ToList());
```

Comment: `"UNION ALL SELECT " + string.Join("UNION ALL SELECT ", teams.Select(c => c.Id).ToList());`

Comment: Use Aggregate, i.e. `teams.Skip(1).Select(c => c.Id).Aggregate(string.Empty, (str, id) => str + " UNION ALL SELECT " + id)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string.Concat(teams.Skip(1).Select(c => " UNION ALL SELECT " + c.Id));
```

or to avoid the leading space :

```
string.Join(" ", teams.Skip(1).Select(c => "UNION ALL SELECT " + c.Id));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var values = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        var str = values
            .Select(i => $"UNION ALL SELECT {i} ")
            .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, a) => sb.Append(a), s => s.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

[C# fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tgu3lj)